# Ordering across columns in a dataframe based on a custom list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I can see solutions for sorting records vertically however I want to arrange a subset of my data in my dataframe horizontally.

Here's my dataframe with data I want to sort:

```
account_num Word_0    Word_1    Word_2    Word_3    Word_4
123         Silver    Platinum  Osmium    
456         Platinum  
789         Silver    Rhodium   Platinum  Osmium
```

and here is my desired output:

```
account_num  Word_0     Word_1    Word_2   Word_3   Word_4
123          Platinum   Osmium    Silver   
456          Platinum   
789          Rhodium    Platinum  Osmium   Silver
```

Based on the order within this dataframe:

```
Priority    Metal
1           Rhodium
2           Platinum
3           Gold
4           Ruthenium
5           Iridium
6           Osmium
7           Palladium
8           Rhenium
9           Silver
10          Indium
```

I have already managed to tidy up my data using this piece of code :

```
newdf.apply(lambda r: sorted(r,reverse = True), axis = 1)
```

where columns Word_0 to 4 are placed in another dataframe (newdf) and then sorted in reverse order so the blank values appear last and they are then joined back to my original dataframe containing the account_num column however I have no idea how to incorporate a custom list in the ordering sequence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)

```
c = pd.Categorical(df2.Metal, df2.Metal, ordered=True)

df.set_index('account_num').transform(lambda k: pd.Categorical(k, 
                                                           categories=c.categories)\
                                  .sort_values(), axis=1)
```

Outputs

```
            Word_0       Word_1     Word_2  Word_3  Word_4
account_num                 
123         Platinum     Osmium     Silver  NaN     NaN
456         Platinum     NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN
789         Rhodium      Platinum   Osmium  Silver  NaN
```

Of course, can always `.fillna('')` in the end.

Comment: i really gotta learn `pd.Categorical()` seems very useful in a lot of cases. :)

Answer (score 3):

I feel like we can `melt` it , the `merge` the order df , then `sort_values` base on the `Priority` , and `pivot` it back

```
s=df.melt('account_num').\
     merge(orderdf,left_on='value',right_on='Metal',how='left').\
       sort_values('Priority')
yourdf=s.assign(newkey=s.groupby('account_num').cumcount()).\
           pivot('account_num','newkey','value').add_prefix('Word_')
yourdf
Out[1100]: 
newkey         Word_0    Word_1  Word_2  Word_3 Word_4
account_num                                           
123          Platinum    Osmium  Silver    None    NaN
456          Platinum      None    None    None    NaN
789           Rhodium  Platinum  Osmium  Silver    NaN
```

---

Or we using more clear logic with `argsort`

```
d = dict(zip(df2['Metal'], df2['Priority']))
for x in range(len(df)):

    df.iloc[x,:]=df.values[x,np.argsort([d.get(x) if x ==x else 1000 for x in df.values[x,:]] )]

df
Out[38]: 
                 Word_0    Word_1  Word_2  Word_3  Word_4
  account_num                                            
0 123          Platinum    Osmium  Silver     NaN     NaN
1 456          Platinum       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2 789           Rhodium  Platinum  Osmium  Silver     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
df=df.fillna(value=pd.np.nan)
d=dict(zip(ref.Metal,ref.Priority))
df[['account_num']].join(pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.iloc[:,1:].replace(d).values,axis=1),
                        columns=df.iloc[:,1:].columns).replace({v:k for k,v in d.items()}))

   account_num    Word_0    Word_1  Word_2  Word_3 Word_4
0          123  Platinum    Osmium  Silver     NaN    NaN
1          456  Platinum       NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2          789   Rhodium  Platinum  Osmium  Silver    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#create helper dictionary
d = dict(zip(df2['Metal'], df2['Priority']))
#add empty string for maximum priority
d[''] = df2['Priority'].max() + 1

#use sorted by key and dictioanry
L = [sorted(x, key=d.get) for x in df.fillna('').values]
#create new DataFrame by constructor
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).add_prefix('Word_')
print (df1)
               Word_0    Word_1  Word_2  Word_3 Word_4
account_num                                           
123          Platinum    Osmium  Silver               
456          Platinum                                 
789           Rhodium  Platinum  Osmium  Silver
```

If need missing values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).add_prefix('Word_').replace('', np.nan)
print (df1)
               Word_0    Word_1  Word_2  Word_3  Word_4
account_num                                            
123          Platinum    Osmium  Silver     NaN     NaN
456          Platinum       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
789           Rhodium  Platinum  Osmium  Silver     NaN
```